# Not able to get $_POST assigned to a variable PHP

Tags: php

I assume I have something stupid happening due to my lack of experience.

On a form on members.php I have:

```
$column = 0;
echo "<Form Name =member Method =POST ACTION = individual.php>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
   while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($column == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo '<td><INPUT TYPE = Submit NAME="'. $row['num'].'" VALUE ="'. $row['name'].'" id=Submit></td>'; 
        $column++;
        if ($column >= 5) {
            echo "</tr>";
            $row++;
            $column=0;
        }
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

On individual.php I have

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

With the result being `Array ( [16] => LUKE )` which is what is expected.

but when I try to

```
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $num=$_POST['num'];
 echo "<br>".$name." ".$num."<br>";
```

I do not get any results.

I mainly want to get  `$row['num']` but also did `['name']` to make sure I didn't transpose what I was trying to achieve.

I basically want to take what was selected on previous form and insert into a

`select * from table where number=$num;`

Comment: Best quasi-coded form/question I've ever saw.

Comment: So where are `name` and `num` ever sent?

Comment: You have only `16` key in post, so you should write something like `$_POST[16]`, weird!

Comment: @Ali `INPUT TYPE = Submit NAME="'. $row['num'].'" VALUE ="'. $row['name'].'" id=Submit`

Comment: @u_mulder  the `16` key is based off of which button is selected. If I select a different button a different value is sent like `Array ( [15] => Bill )`

Comment: OK I see what is being said and it is a bit clearer; thank you. but I am now stuck trying to accomplish what I am trying to do. `echo '<td><INPUT TYPE = Hidden NAME="num" VALUE ="'. $row['num'].'" id=Submit><INPUT TYPE = Submit NAME="name" VALUE ="'.$row['name'].'"></td>';` now keeps passing with `$name=$_POST['name'];
$num=$_POST['num]` results in  `LUKE 16 9` with the `9` being associated with the last name in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your input fields are not `num` and `name`, instead, they are the ***values*** of these two keys in the array `$row`. That is why you are unable to retrieve these values on the backend.

Change your code to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>;">
<input type="hidden" name="num" value="<?php echo $row['num']; ?>;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" name="submit_form">
```

Answer (score 0):

For obtain POST value for 'name' and 'num', you have to write:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="num" value="<?php echo $row['num']; ?>">
```

type can be 'text' or 'hidden'

Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form to return values that you can access using `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['num']`, you need to set `name` and `num` as input names on your form, and the appropriate values as the input values. If you don't want to add them as visible/editable values in your form, the usual way to do it is to use inputs of type `hidden`:

```
<form action="individual.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="16" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="LUKE" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

As it is, `$_POST` does contain the values that you're want, but they're not in an accessible format, because you've set `16` as an input `name`, so it turns into a key in the `$_POST` associative array. The form above will set `num` and `name` as keys in `$_POST`, and `16` and `LUKE` respectively as the values.